# Exception in thread "main" java.util.UnknownFormatConversionException: Conversion = '-'

Tags: java, implicit-conversion

The problem is "Conversion = '-'".
The source code is here, I had commented the "printf" to avoid some problems, always cased by "print": **this is a program used for calculating Loan in year**.

```
import java.util.*;
public class Loan{
    public static void main(String args[]){
        final double MIN = 0.05;
        final double MAX = 0.08;
        final double ADD = 0.125;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Loan Amount: ");
        double amount = input.nextDouble();
        System.out.print("Number of Years :");
        int years = input.nextInt();
        /*  
        for(double r = MIN; r < MAX;r = r + ADD){
          double R = Math.pow((1+r),years);
          double monthlyPayment = r * R * amount / 12/(R-1);
          double totalPayment = 12*monthlyPayment*years;
          System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20\n","InterestRate","MonthlyPayment","TotalPayment");
          System.out.printf("%%-20f%-20.2f%-20.2f\n",r,monthlyPayment,totalPayment);
         }
         */     
     }
}
```

Comment: which statement is throwing the exception?

Comment: and what does your input looks like?

Answer (score 15):

You're missing a format specifier character, replace

```
System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20", "InterestRate", ...)
```

with

```
System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s", "InterestRate", ...
                                 ^
```

Answer (score 1):

I Guess you want this,

```
System.out.printf("%-20s%-20s%-20s", "InterestRate",
        "MonthlyPayment", "TotalPayment\n");
System.out.printf("%-20.2f%-20.2f%-20.2f\n", r, monthlyPayment,
        totalPayment);
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below code it will work

```
System.out.printf("%-20s %-20s %20s %n","InterestRate","Monthly Payment","Total Payment\n");               
System.out.printf("%-20f %-20.2f %-20.2f\n",r,monthlyPayment,totalPayment);
```

Let me know if anything else required